# Want to replace the text between [explanation] and [explanation] - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
This is your question?

[x] Option A

[ ] Option B

[x] Option C

[x] Option D

[explanation]

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="X" >View</a>

[explanation]
```

Comment: show your code what you have tried ?

Comment: Can you give some more details on what exactly you want to do? replace the text in the Anchor(a tag) tag? I mean the text "View"

Comment: It'd be better to use JavaScript to remove the element from the DOM instead of using regex. If you **still** want to use regex, use [`/(\[explanation\])[\s\S]+\1/gmi`](https://regex101.com/r/kW8dD8/2)

Comment: @Tushar regex working fine, but what about the browser compatibility?

Comment: @DadasoZanzane It supports all browsers, there'll be no problem

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace a string between two other strings (e.g, img tag), please use this...

```
var output = input.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '').replace (/\[explanation\](.*?)\[explanation\]/g, "your string replacement");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution -

```
var output = input.replace (/(\[explanation\])[\s\S]+\1/gmi, "[explanation]\n\n"+"My New String"+"\n\n[explanation]" );
```